# How do inserts into sqlite views work?

Tags: view, insert, sqlite

I have a database schema which is identical in files 1.sqlitedb through n.sqlitedb. I use a view to 'merge' all of the databases. My question is: when i insert into the view, into which database does the data get inserted into? Is there any way to control which gets the data? The way that i need to split the data depends on the data itself. Essentially, i use the first letter of a field to determine the file that it gets inserted into. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you split the data across multiple files? There is no practical limit on file size in sqlite.

Comment: I don't think you can. Try using expression in place of database name you want to insert into, but I fear it will be syntax error.

Comment: the letters are drive letters. The database is a composite of seperate removable databases and hence the files are on different drives

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Writing to views is NOT supported for SQLite like it is with other dbs.

http://www.sqlite.org/omitted.html

In order to achieve similar functionality, one must create triggers to do the necessary work.

Answer (score 3):

We need to implement instead of trigger on the view (VIEW_NAME) . So when insert/update happens view . we can insert update underlying object (TABLE_NAME) in the trigger body.

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name  instead of INSERT on VIEW_NAME
BEGIN
       insert into TABLE_NAME ( col1 ,col2 ) values ( :new.col1, :new.col2);
END;

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but have you looked into using the ATTACH DATABASE command?  It allows you connect separate database files to a single database.  You can control INSERTs into a specific database by prefixing the database name (INSERT INTO db1.Table).

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html